# Problems with my java loop

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement, dice

I want to make a dice which keeps getting thrown until it hits 6:
When it hits 1, it pops up with 1 and an one eyed dice and throws again,..
just with random numbers (1-6 obviously) until it hits 6. When it hits 6
it is supposed to stop.

Now I had this switch here which showed the proper number when hit, but I'm having troubles getting this switch working properly. Or it hits all numbers BUT six and keeps generating numbers, or it keeps throwing the same numbers.

Can anyone lend me a hand?

Very appreciated

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // asking what symbol to use to print the eye(s) of the dice
    System.out.print("choose symbol to use for eyes: ");

    char ch;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ch = sc.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
    int dice = (int)(6*Math.random()) + 1;


    do{
        switch(dice % 6){
            case 0: System.out.println("1");
                    System.out.println(ch);
            break;
            case 1: System.out.println("2");
                    System.out.println(ch  + "\n\n " + ch);
            break;
            case 2: System.out.println("3");
                    System.out.println(ch + "\n " + ch + "\n  " + ch);
            break;
            case 3: System.out.println("4");
                    System.out.println(ch + " " + ch + "\n" + ch + " " + ch);
            break;
            case 4: System.out.println("5");
                    System.out.println(ch + " " + ch + "\n" + " " + ch + " \n"+ ch + " " + ch);
            break;
        }
    }
    while(dice < 6);
      //  Else{ System.out.println("6");
       //         System.out.println(ch + " " + ch + "\n" + ch + " " + ch + "\n" + ch +
        //        " " + ch);
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Because you are only randomly generating a number once.

Comment: Your loop condition is wrong it should be dice%6==0. Generate random number in the loop/

Comment: There's another issue that needs to be covered. Your dice value will be 1 to 6. Then you take the modulus of that. 1 % 6 = 1, but you have that set as case 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you generating your random number outside of the loop, so it will be same for ever here is the working version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // asking what symbol to use to print the eye(s) of the dice
    System.out.print("choose symbol to use for eyes: ");

    char ch;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ch = sc.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
    int dice = (int)(6*Math.random()) + 1;


    do{
        switch(dice % 6){
            case 0: System.out.println("1");
                    System.out.println(ch);
            break;
            case 1: System.out.println("2");
                    System.out.println(ch  + "\n\n " + ch);
            break;
            case 2: System.out.println("3");
                    System.out.println(ch + "\n " + ch + "\n  " + ch);
            break;
            case 3: System.out.println("4");
                    System.out.println(ch + " " + ch + "\n" + ch + " " + ch);
            break;
            case 4: System.out.println("5");
                    System.out.println(ch + " " + ch + "\n" + " " + ch + " \n"+ ch + " " + ch);
            break;
        }
        dice = (int)(6*Math.random()) + 1;
    }
    while(dice < 6);
    System.out.println("6");
       //         System.out.println(ch + " " + ch + "\n" + ch + " " + ch + "\n" + ch +
        //        " " + ch);
 }
```

[here](http://ideone.com/A3LRkt) is the online working version.

Comment: This does work, but now it does not show 6 when it is 6. how do implement "if dice = 6 then show six and stop"? and can you tell me why i have to put the dice in the loop and above it. I can see it works with them being there both and not when I remove one,.. don't understand why. thanks for the reply though

Comment: @Rick if you want to show the eyes for six just remove two last line comments from my code, you didn't have to put the dice above the loop, I just want it looks more like your code, you could simply put int dice = (int)(6*Math.random()) + 1; inside your loop and it will work because for every iteration it will generate another random number. I hope this help. please if its what you want mark this answer.

Comment: thanks! so basically... you can just say what's supposed to happen when it is not having the conditions mentioned in the while, after the while? So while(dice <6); and next row say what should happen when it is bigger then 5?

Comment: @Rick exactly, although it could be if(dice == 6)

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the following inside the loop:

```
int dice = (int)(6*Math.random()) + 1;
```

(Otherwise you effectively throw the die just once.)

Also, the way you generate the random number, the way you switch on it, and the `while` condition are not quite consistent with each other.

Comment: thanks for the reply. how would you suggest doing it without the switch?